# reading data file for root cern graphing

Tags: c++, text-files, graphing, root-framework

I created a script to take data from a text file and graph it in Root (CERN) but haven't used root in about a year, updated to the current version of Root and now it gets the error "Error: Function readprn() is not defined in current scope  :0:
*** Interpreter error recovered ***" when i try to use it with Root.

It runs an excel data file that I saved as a txt file. The first column is the x value corresponding to each y value in the subsequent 768 columns. At the end it graphs and fits and loops over a couple graphs.

I'm mostly wondering if there is anything in the new versions that would cause this to not be able to be read by root.

```
#include <TGraph.h>
#include <TCanvas.h>
#include <TF1.h>
#include <TMath.h>
#include <TStyle.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;    using std::endl;

int threshold1(Int_t channel=0)
{
    const char* ifname = "thresholdScanRun110FPGA4.txt";

    cout<< "processing file " << ifname <<endl;
    std::ifstream ifile(ifname);
    if (!ifile) {
        cout<< "Could not find file " << ifname <<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //std::string line;
    // discard the first two lines
    //std::getline(ifile, line);
    //cout<< line <<endl;
    //std::getline(ifile, line);
    //cout<< line <<endl;

    std::string str;
    double number;

    // read the first row (in sense of Exel's row)
    ifile >> str;
    //cout<< str <<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<768; ++i) {
        ifile >> number;
        //cout<< number << " ";
    }
    //cout<<endl;
    // read the second "row"
    ifile >> str;
    //cout<< str <<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<768; ++i) {
        ifile >> number;
        //cout<< number << " ";
    }
    //cout<<endl;

    double thres[60];
    double prob[60][768];
    int nthres_max = 60;

    for (int ithres=0; ithres<nthres_max; ++ithres) {
        ifile >> thres[ithres];
        for (int iprob=0; iprob<768; ++iprob) ifile >> prob[ithres][iprob];
    }

    cout<< "The channel " << channel <<endl;
    for (int ithres=0; ithres<60; ++ithres) {
        cout<< thres[ithres] << " " << prob[ithres][channel] <<endl;
    }

    Double_t probability[60];
    for (int ithres=0; ithres<60; ++ithres) probability[ithres] = prob[ithres][channel];
    TGraph* gr = new TGraph(60, thres, probability);
    gr->SetMarkerStyle(29);
    gr->SetMarkerColor(4);
    gr->SetTitle("Threshold Scan ChipX, ChanY");

    TF1* ferfc = new TF1("ferfc", "0.5*TMath::Erfc((x-[0])/[1])", 0, 767);
    ferfc->SetParameters(100,10);

    new TCanvas;
    gStyle->SetOptFit(1);
    gr->Draw("apl");
    gr->Fit("ferfc");

    return 0;
}

int threshold_all()
{
    for (Int_t channel=0; channel<2; ++channel) {
        threshold1(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need the c++ Tag.

Comment: "Interpreter error received" could imply that you are just running this script without compiling it.  Have you compiled it yet?  If not, please compile it outside of ROOT.  ROOT fairly recently went from v5 to v6, and the CINT interpreter has been replaced with cling (no, not clang), which is much more restrictive as to what it will allow.  That said, compile it with gcc or clang and run outside of ROOT.  It should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

when loading your macro in root 6.07/04, with `.L macro.C` I receive the following warning:

```
/tmp/tmp.rQTNVdlydv/macro.C:88:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]
```

which is because you don't have a return statement in `int threshold_all()`. Fixing this the macro seems fine to me. (runs, opens a canvas, some fit output. Since I don't have your input values, I just created a text file with a few invented numbers and reduced the number of thresholds and values to 5x6. Which is why I'm not concerned about the abnormal fit termination which I receive.).

Also loading the macro with compilation `.L macro.C+` looks fine to me once adding the return statement.